# Update SQL Query in child BU from a parent BU using WSProxy

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Could you please let me know what's wrong with my code?

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

//Switch context to different BU. Change the MID to suit.
 prox.setClientId({"ID": 99999999});
 try {
 var query_string = "select top 10 name from table"
 var dataExtensionCustomerKey = "dataExtensionCustomerKey";

 var queryObj = {
    ObjectID: queryObjectObjectID,
    Name: dataExtensionCustomerKey,
    CustomerKey: dataExtensionCustomerKey,
    Description: "Description",
    QueryText: query_string,
    TargetUpdateType: 'Overwrite',
    DataExtensionTarget: {
        CustomerKey: "tyasduysgduchi",
        Name: "sql"
    }

};
 var update_status = prox.updateItem("QueryDefinition", queryObj);
 Write(Stringify(update_status)+"<br><br>")

 if (update_status == 'OK') {
    sleep(5000);
  prox.performItem("QueryDefinition", queryObj);
 }

} catch (err) {
 Write(Stringify(err))
} 

//reset the context if required
prox.resetClientIds();
</script>
```

Getting error:

```
"Status": "Error",
"RequestID": "asasadds1232435",
"Results": [{
"Object": {
        "CustomerKey": "query",
        "Name": "query",
        "Status": "Active",
        "ObjectID": "6572345748",
        "QueryText": "select * from table",
        "TargetType": null,
        "DataExtensionTarget": null,
        "TargetUpdateType": "Overwrite",
        "FileSpec": null,
        "FileType": null,
        "CategoryID": 0,
        "InteractionObjectID": null,
        "Description": "desc",
        "Keyword": null,
        "Client": {
            "ID": 99999,
            "ClientID1": 0,
            "PartnerClientKey": null,
            "UserID": 0,
            "PartnerUserKey": null,
            "CreatedBy": 0,
            "ModifiedBy": 0,
            "EnterpriseID": 0,
            "CustomerKey": null,
            "CustomerID": null
        },
        "PartnerKey": null,
        "PartnerProperties": null,
        "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000",
        "ModifiedDate": null,
        "ID": 0,
        "Owner": null,
        "CorrelationID": null,
        "ObjectState": null,
        "IsPlatformObject": false
    },
    "UpdateResults": null,
    "ParentPropertyName": null,
    "StatusCode": "Error",
    "StatusMessage": "Exception occurred during [UpdateQueryDefinition] ErrorID: 98517498",
    "OrdinalID": 0,
    "ErrorCode": 2,
    "RequestID": null,
    "ConversationID": null,
    "OverallStatusCode": null,
    "RequestType": "Synchronous",
    "ResultType": null,
    "ResultDetailXML": null
}]
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you are trying to achieve with your code and what errors you are getting..

Comment: @RachidMamai I am trying to update a QueryActivity locate in a Child BU, running the SSJS from the parent BU, the error got from catch is the following: {
    "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "description": "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - from Jint\r\n\r\n"
}

Comment: And you verified the query target data extension's customer/external key?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs the query customer key is in the code, but the data extension customer isn’t there, as I only want to update the Query.

Comment: The same code works if I don't try to impersonate the child BU, but unfortunately the SQL is in the child BU, and I need to run it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it working using SSJS and Rest, thanks [Gortonington](https://stackexchange.com/users/4498970/gortonington), for your articles https://gortonington.com/how-to-interact-with-query-activities-via-rest-api/ and https://gortonington.com/restapimethodinssjs/

Answer (score 2):

When updating a QueryDefinition object via SOAP(WSProxy would have the same limitation), it requires that the ObjectID be passed.  It will not find it based on CustomerKey alone. A retrieve can be used to find the ObjectID.

Comment: Thanks Mac, I had retrieve the ObjectID, and passed it in the 

var queryObj = {
        Name: dataExtensionCustomerKey,
        CustomerKey: dataExtensionCustomerKey,
        Description: "desc",
        QueryText: query_string,
        TargetUpdateType: 'Overwrite',
        ObjectID: queryObjectObjectID
    };

But I am still getting the "StatusMessage": "Exception occurred during [UpdateQueryDefinition] ErrorID: 1041625481"

And the catch error "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",

Answer (score 2):

I did notice that your [perform WSProxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_perform.htm) is malformed. This may be the cause for the error.

First you are missing some of the parameters to be passed in it.

```
prox.performItem("QueryDefinition", queryObj);
```

should be

```
prox.performItem("QueryDefinition", props, action, opts);
```

Where `props` is the object stating the ObjectID of the query you want to perform:

```
var props = {
    ObjectID: queryObjID 
};
```

`action` should be `"Start"` as you are running the Query.

`opts` is fine to leave as an empty object like:

```
var opts = {};
```

Your current object you are passing to the perform call (`queryObj`) is not formatted correctly for this action, which is likely causing issues. I also did notice that inside this object you use both `"` and `'` to denote constant strings - it is highly recommended you instead just use `"` on both.

Outside that, I would try commenting out the executions and just write each part of it to ensure that it is filling in correct information.  Then I would take this info and verify in the child BU that they actually exist. If those both are accurate, then I would first try just the update call. If that succeeds, then attempt the perform (with above adjustments).  If after all this it is still failing, at least you know have a stronger idea on what part is causing the issue which should make it easier to debug.

Answer (score 2):

The non-WSProxy method for updating queries is a lot more straightforward, IMO.  Here's an example that I pulled from a Script Activity that I have running:

```javascript
  var addObj = {}
  addObj.Name = queryNameAndExternalKey;
  addObj.CustomerKey = queryNameAndExternalKey;
  addObj.QueryText = queryText;
  addObj.TargetType = "DE";
  addObj.TargetUpdateType = action;
  addObj.Target = {};
  addObj.Target.Name = foundDENameAndExternalKey;
  addObj.Target.CustomerKey = foundDENameAndExternalKey;
  addObj.CategoryID = foundQueryCategoryID;

  var addStatus = QueryDefinition.Add(addObj);

  if (addStatus != "OK") {

    var updateObj = {};
    updateObj.QueryText = queryText;
    updateObj.TargetType = "DE";
    updateObj.TargetUpdateType = action;
    updateObj.Target = {};
    updateObj.Target.Name = foundDENameAndExternalKey;
    updateObj.Target.CustomerKey = foundDENameAndExternalKey;
    updateObj.CategoryID = foundQueryCategoryID;

    var qd = QueryDefinition.Init(queryNameAndExternalKey);
    var updateStatus = qd.Update(updateObj);

  }
```